# Incomplete class: Convert void* to pointer to class type via dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, casting, forward-declaration, dynamic-cast, incomplete-type

I have 2 classes A and B. B is derived from A. A has a function pointer member, for which the argument is an object of B. The classes are defined as follows:

```
class B;
typedef double (*func_ptr)(B *);

class A
{
  private:
    func_ptr func;
};

class B: public A
{
  private:
    double C;
};
```

When I try to dynamic cast a void* into A* or B*, I get the following error:

```
void *v_ptr;
A *a_ptr = dynamic_cast<A*>(v_ptr);
B *b_ptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(v_ptr);

error: the operand of a pointer dynamic_cast must be a pointer to a complete class type
```

I have no clue why this is happening. There are no virtual methods in either of the classes. I know that forward declaration of a class cannot be used to declare members, but here it's being used to define a pointer.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: *"When I try to dynamic cast a void*"* - That's not allowed with dynamic_cast. Your whole problem is in that sentence.

Comment: Probably a transcription error, but if not this semicolon `private;` isn't doing you any favours.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, sorry that's private:

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert `void*` by [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), the expression required by `dynamic_cast` must refer to a complete class type, while `void` is not.

(emphasis mine)

> lvalue of a **complete class type** if `new_type` is a reference, prvalue of a pointer to **complete class type** if `new_type` is a pointer.

BTW: The converting type should refer to a complete class type too.

> pointer to complete class type, reference to complete class type, or pointer to (optionally cv-qualified) void

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. I should use static_cast

Answer (score 1):

The operand of `dynamic_cast`must be a pointer to a complete class type ([[expr.dynamic.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.dynamic.cast)):

> 1. The result of the expression `dynamic_­cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression v to type T....
> 2. If T is a pointer type, v shall be a prvalue of a pointer to complete class type, and the result is a prvalue of type T...

Furthermore, it's really unclear *why* you are using `dynamic_cast` at all. The classes in your example are not polymorphic. There are no virtual functions in sight.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. I should use static_cast